# Are there more data structures available to Python (2.7) than the standard list, set, tuple dict in the standard library?

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-structures

I've been going through the coursera courses on algorithms, and it seems to me that Python doesn't have as rich of collection of data structures as the ones presented there.

Java's collections seem much more diverse.

For instance, if i'd like to have collections specialized in either insertion at the end / in the middle, or a sorted data structure that does allow for duplicates.

Do I need to implement these collections for myself, or have I just not looked for them hard enough?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Python's standard and external libraries contain many additional data structures:

- See the [collections](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module for namedtuple, deque, Counters, OrderedDict and defaultdict.
- See the [heapq](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) module for heaps, which can be used as priority-queues.
- See [numpy/scipy](http://www.scipy.org/) for n-dimensional matrix datatypes, including all thinkable linear algebra, similar to Matlab.
- See [networkx](http://networkx.github.io/) for graph datatypes and algorithms.
- See [blist](http://stutzbachenterprises.com/blist/) for a list implemented as a [b-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_tree), which has much better performance for inserting in the middle of the list.
- See [bisect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) for searching/inserting in  sorted lists.
- See [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) for a datatype for time-calculations.
- See [queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) for a queue that can be used for thread-safe passing of messages.
- See [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) for a double-ended queue to which you can efficiently add and remove items on either side (but random access in the middle is more expensive).
- See [fractions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) for a datatype for old-school math with fractional numbers

It would probably be hard to find a datatype that has not already been implemented in Python, or which is implemented in some C/fortran-library with Python bindings. There might be some datatypes, like linked-lists, that are not really used in Python, since there are better/easier alternatives.

Answer (score 7):

There are a lot more (linked to their document references):

- [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)
- [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)
- [`tuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)
- [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)
- [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)
- [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)
- [`deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)
- [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)
- [`defauldict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)
- [`array`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html)
- [`heapq`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html)
- [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html)

If you care to venture outside of the Python standard library, there are many specialized libraries that provide other structures. numpy for example has a very comprehensive [array object](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.html), the following is their description:

> NumPy provides an N-dimensional array type, the ndarray, which
>   describes a collection of “items” of the same type. The items can be
>   indexed using for example N integers.
>
> All ndarrays are homogenous: every item takes up the same size block
>   of memory, and all blocks are interpreted in exactly the same way. How
>   each item in the array is to be interpreted is specified by a separate
>   data-type object, one of which is associated with every array. In
>   addition to basic types (integers, floats, etc.), the data type
>   objects can also represent data structures.
>
> An item extracted from an array, e.g., by indexing, is represented by
>   a Python object whose type is one of the array scalar types built in
>   Numpy. The array scalars allow easy manipulation of also more
>   complicated arrangements of data.